# deleting files from firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

So I'm allowing user's upload certain images in the storage of firebase, and each file is named after their user id. So when a user uploads an image, I get a url that for that file

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jobify-a7a4a.appspot.com/o/CZx5biMydzQAOx4T8WXJU5jt2852%2Fimages%2Fdreamy-waterfall-4k-sc.jpg?alt=media&token=8e4d60ed-e956-4f71-80d1-58755fe94dbe`

And so when a user changes the uploaded image, I'd like to delete the previously updated image from the storage.
I've seen how they do it in the docs, but that requires the file name which I don't have access to.

This is the code when a user uploads an image

```
function uploadImg(e) {
const file = e.target.files[0];

if (file && file.size < 30000000) {
  var storageRef = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref(`${user.uid}/images`)
    .child(file.name);
  const task = storageRef.put(file);
  task.on(
    "state_changes",
    function progress(snap) {
      setLoading(true);
      const percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
      loadingref.current.style.height = percentage + "%";
    },
    function error() {
      setNotifibool(true);
      setNotifi({
        text: "Try Again!",
        icon: "fal fa-exclamation-circle"
      });
    },
    function complete() {
      setLoading(false);
      storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        setState(url);
      });
      setNotifi({
        text: "Image Uploaded!",
        icon: "fal fa-check-circle"
      });
    }
  );
} else {
  window.alert("too big");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate the download URL you have back to a reference by calling [`firebase.storage().refFromUrl(downloadUrl)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#reffromurl). Then your can delete the file by calling [`delete`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#delete) on that reference.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to check if the referenced url file exist in storage?

Comment: When i do this, I get an error Firebase Storage: refFromUrl() expected a valid full URL but got an invalid one. I don't know if has to do with allowing users to also provide img urls, which are not being saved in storage. .

Comment: Calling `refFromUrl()` with a URL that is not from Firebase Storage will indeed not work, and throw an error.

Comment: Any solution? To check if it is firebase url?

Comment: Nothing build in that I know of. But they seem to start with `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/$yourproject.appspot.com/o`, so that would be one way to check. And you can also check based on the error you get back.

Comment: So i can do .includes("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/$yourproject.appspot.com/o") AS a way to verify?